# Is there any plan for a date-picker component for react-bootstrap in the future?

Tags: datepicker, react-bootstrap

Any plan for date-picker component in the future for react-bootstrap library ?
It seems helpful.

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards,

Comment: I think you should ask this kind of questions on the projects site / github repo.

Comment: I agree that this sort of question should be in the project's issue list. However, I can tell you the answer is no. React-Bootstrap only focuses on the components from the core Bootstrap library. A date picker is not one of them.